# first-line pseudo element not working for p element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

```css
p::first-line {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

As you can see, the first line hasn't been converted to uppercase. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using OS X 10.11.6, and Safari 9.1.2 (11601.7.7).

Comment: I'm with Firefox Android and it works.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Edited my question to specify the platform: maybe some non-standard factors were involved in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your pseudo-element works just fine. The issue you are facing is a known, 10+ year-old, unsolved bug in the Webkit Engine regarding **`::first-line`** not accepting **`text-transform`**.

This particular bug has been reported multiple times, but it seems like there is no solution whatsoever. Check out three of the reports I found:

- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=142827
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=129669
- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3409

```css
p::first-line {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

---

For the record, the properties **`::first-line`** accepts are:

- font properties
- color properties
- background properties
- word-spacing
- letter-spacing
- text-decoration
- vertical-align
- text-transform
- line-height
- clear

You can find more about **`::first-line`** in [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstline.asp).

---

Note: Bug [129669](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=129669) on Chromium has been fixed since September 26<sup>th</sup> 2017.

Comment: It's most likely browser issue @MarcosPérezGude. I doesn't work for me in **`Chrome 52.0.2743.116`**, but it works in the latest Firefox and also my android browser.

Comment: As usual, firefox wins chrome

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude both have their nuisances.

Comment: With the difference in Firefox rules the community and in Chrome only works by Google decisions.

Comment: That's indeed one plus for Firefox.

Comment: Absolutely. Do you know open source concept?

Comment: The bug 129669 you mentioned is fixed now. The code works fine on Google Chrome.

Comment: That's great news @KolappanNathan. It was about time!

Comment: @AngelPolitis Could you please update the answer to include this info.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently `::first-line` and `text-transform` combination does not work in webkit browsers. In Firefox, your code works fine. Check [this bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=129669).

Comment: So this is my browser's bug?

Comment: Yes. It is still an open issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the properties that are excluded from use with `::first-line` [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-line/). Among them are

```
.element::first-line {
    font-style: ...
    font-variant: ...
    font-weight: ...
    font-size: ...
    font-family: ...

    line-height: ...
    color: ...
    word-spacing: ...
    letter-spacing: ...
    text-decoration: ...
    **text-transform: ...**

    background-color: ...
    background-image: ...
    background-position: ...
    background-repeat: ...
    background-size: ...
    background-attachment: ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. **It turned out that I made the `p` element to `{display: inline;}`:**

```
     p {
         font-size: 22px;
         line-height: 1.5;
         margin-bottom: 15px;              
         display: inline;  // this is the problem.
     }
```

But I forgot that.

So later when I was trying the following pseudo class:

```
     p::first-line {
         color: red;
     }
```

No matter what I did, the pseudo class just didn't work.

Then I thought I might have done something to the `p` element.

I went back and checked, and I found I made the `p` element to `{display: inline;}`. **I deleted `display: inline;`, and then the pseudo class started to work.**